# CppCMS template tutorial: Where controller should be?

Tags: c++, cppcms

From http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello_templates

The controller is:

```
virtual void main(std::string /*url*/)
{
    content::message c;
    c.text=">>>Hello<<<";
    render("message",c);
}
```

It says:

> but before this we include our `content.h` header

Means it is in different file, but I dont know where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a file named whatever you like. However, the compiler command below presumes you called it `hello.cpp`. This `hello.cpp` should have `#include "content.h"` at the top of it.

Answer (score 2):

> before this we include our content.h header

Only means that the controller needs the header `content.h` in order to use: `content::message c;` (the `content` namespace used at the beginning of the tutorial). Which just means that you should add: `#include "content.h"` on the top of the controller file.

The controller file can be named whatever you want. The tutorial, however, expect you to call it `hello.cpp` near the end of the tutorial. Therefore you should call it that way (at least when following the tutorial).

Comment: What name of the controller file? From the tutorial, the only files I know is `content.h` and `my_skin.tmpl`